# How to disable an automatic conversion of styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I'm working on a project that uses styled components as a means of styling css in javascript. But it automatically adds css properties to make them compatible with older browsers. For me this is a little unnecessary, and it weighs even more on the site loading, so I would like to disable this feature in styled-components. I'm using webpack and babel.

I will give an example.

> This is the code I want to get:

```
.dialog-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

> The code looks like this after compilation:

```
.dialog-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need wrap your application in the StyleSheetManager component.

Also you need pass disableVendorPrefixes prop to him. And then vendor prefix will be disable.

Docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#stylesheetmanager

In example below you will not see prefix for flex property.

```
import styled, { StyleSheetManager } from "styled-components";

const Component = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const App = () => (
  <StyleSheetManager disableVendorPrefixes>
    <Component>2</Component>
  </StyleSheetManager>
);
```